# TypeError when using cxfreeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am attempting to make my first .exe file using cx_freeze on 32-bit Ubuntu, but am encountering an unexplained TypeError. I expect I have done something wrong in my setup file, but have yet to find what it might be. Here is the setup script:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


exe = Executable(
    script = 'cornell7.py',
    targetName = 'cornell7.exe',
    packages = ['header2.py'],
    targetDir = 'executable_dir',
    includes = [    'urllib.request', 'socket', 'sys', 'string', 'threading', 'time','datetime'],
    copyDependentFiles = True
    )
setup(    name = 'cornell7.exe',
          executables = [exe]
     )
```

(header2.py is a module I myself wrote containing several useful functions)

Here is the command I've been running in the terminal:

```
 python setup.py build
```

When I enter that command, I get the following error message:

```
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "setup.py", line 14, in <module>
      executables = [exe]
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/dist.py", line 278, in setup
     distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
     cmd_obj.run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
     self.run_command(cmd_name)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
     self.distribution.run_command(command)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
     cmd_obj.run()
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/dist.py", line 165, in run
     freezer.Freeze()
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 405, in Freeze
     self._FreezeExecutable(executable)
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 149, in _FreezeExecutable
    scriptModule = finder.IncludeFile(exe.script, exe.moduleName)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 391, in IncludeFile
    deferredImports)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 286, in _LoadModule
     self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 353, in _ScanCode
     module, relativeImportIndex)
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 176, in _ImportModule
     deferredImports)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 246, in _InternalImportModule
     parentModule)
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 286, in _LoadModule
     self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 353, in _ScanCode
     module, relativeImportIndex)
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 176, in _ImportModule
     deferredImports)
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 241, in _InternalImportModule
     fp, path, info = self._FindModule(searchName, path)
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 84, in _FindModule
     for location in path:
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

So far as I can tell, I've obeyed the cx_freeze documentation faithfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a cx_freeze expert, but your executable definition looks wrong. The `packages` argument is supposed to take a list of *packages* (that is, folders containing `__init__.py` and zero or more other Python files), not of Python *modules* (individual `.py` files).

For more information on the difference between modules and packages, see http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Actually, `packages` can take modules as well - the naming is somewhat confusing - but it *shouldn't* have the `.py` extension.